# CoreBluetooth: Unable to reconnect to device after calling cancelConnection()

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth

I'm writing an iOS app which will connect to bluetooth heart rate devices.  There will be multiple screens some of which will need a bluetooth connection and some of which won't.

I've set things up so that I have a BTManager class, which is a singleton.  It holds a reference to a single CBCentralManager and also has other instance variables for the connected peripheral etc.

I have it working so that when the app loads-up a view which needs HR, it calls a `connect()` method on my singleton which uses `retrievePeripherals(withIdentifiers: uuids)`.  When the view unloads it calls: `cancelPeripheralConnection(self.hrPeripheral!)`.

So far all this works, but...

The plan was to call the same `connect()` method when I re-enter the view, but I'm finding that once I've called `cancelPeripheralConnection` it never manages to connect to that peripheral again without re-starting the app.

What is the intended lifecycle of `CBCentralManager`?  Should I be destroying it and recreating it? Any other ideas why this won't work?

Comment: I did notice that if I hook up a button in the UI so I can retry the connect() call, that it does eventually connect again.  Maybe I have to wait a bit before attempting to reconnect?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by putting in retry logic.  I retry the connection 5 times with a configurable delay in between attempts.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).